# Deciphering Xuggle/ffmpeg errors (newbie)

Tags: debugging, ffmpeg, lame, xuggle

I've recently started working with Xuggle to convert video files of various formats into corresponding FLVs (to be played on our site via jwplayer).  The code I'm using is trivially  simple; essentially what they show for the basic video conversion tutorial:

```
IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(file.getPath());
reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeWriter(tempFileName, reader));

while (reader.readPacket() == null)
;
```

This works well for about 50% of the videos I've attempted.  However, I get the following error for some videos (all .MP4s I've come across, as well as some .MOVs)

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error Operation not permitted, failed to write header to container com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer@-635072136[url:/tmp/1280786368521.flv;type:WRITE;format:com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat@-631842520[oname:flv;olongname:FLV format;omimetype:video/x-flv;oextensions:flv;];] while establishing stream com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream@-615272544[index:1;id:2;streamcoder:com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder@-677475184[codec=com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@-635131032[type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO;id=CODEC_ID_MP3;name=libmp3lame;];time base=1/48000;frame rate=0/0;sample rate=48000;channels=2;];framerate:0/0;timebase:1/90000;direction:OUTBOUND;]
        at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(MediaWriter.java:1065)
        at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeAudio(MediaWriter.java:837)
        at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onAudioSamples(MediaWriter.java:1448)
        at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onAudioSamples(AMediaToolMixin.java:89)
        at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchAudioSamples(MediaReader.java:628)
        at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeAudio(MediaReader.java:555)
        at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:469)
        ... 10 more
```

I'm having a hard time determining if the root cause for the error is related to the Xuggle/ffmpeg/lame/etc. installation, or whether there's an issue with my code.

I figure the first step is deciphering the error log and using that info to try to convert the video using native ffmpeg calls.  If that works, I assume it's reasonable to believe that those components are installed correctly?

So for a log message like:

```
Error Operation not permitted, failed to write header to container com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer@-635072136
[url:/tmp/1280786368521.flv;type:WRITE;format:com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat@-631842520[oname:flv;olongname:FLV format;omimetype:video/x-flv;oextensions:flv;];] 

while establishing stream com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream@-615272544
[index:1;id:2;streamcoder:com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder@-677475184[codec=com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@-635131032[type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO;id=CODEC_ID_MP3;name=libmp3lame;];time base=1/48000;frame rate=0/0;sample rate=48000;channels=2;];framerate:0/0;timebase:1/90000;direction:OUTBOUND;]
```

how would I translate that to a ffmpeg command?

any other debugging tips for this Xuggle newbie?

Comment: In playing around a bit with command line ffmpeg, it seems as if the issue is with the audio rate of the input videos being incompatible with the flv output (e.g., 48000 Hz).  If I use the '-ar 44100' option for ffmpeg, the videos convert successfully.  

Now to translate that to Xuggle code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.  It was due to FLV only supporting audio streams with sample rates of 44.1, 22.05 & 11.025 kHz.  Used Xuggle's IAudioResampler class from within a custom MediaTool listener listening to onAudioSamples() to resample the audio to a supported rate.

Answer (score 1):

I also recently ran across this same issue. Spent couple of days on this till I found the answer [here](http://whaticode.com/2010/04/30/use-java-to-convert-any-media-type-to-flv-with-xuggler-part-2/).

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you describe the solution to the question rather than just including a link.

Comment: @xlnc i also tried this, i was trying to convert to 3gp so there was a little difference in minor details but it started throwing a null pointer exception, which i solved by adding a null check in the onAddStream method. Now there is no error, but the program remains busy and a 65 Kb file is formed, which on playing says that the file has no playable streams. Please can u help me in any way here.

Comment: The link you gave is not opening.